# sessionErrorDomain : Invalid token. in api OpenTok Android SDK

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an error when taking more than one section, for it I use ListView for Android code is to store the section, already stored, with each line there is just as much to make the video conference

Error message :sessionErrorDomain : Invalid token.

Make sure you are using latest
OpenTok server SDK(http://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/server
Token:

T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD00NTkwNjk2MiZzaWc9NDU4YTZkNDVjNDcwMWUyY2M5OTFiNTI4NDliY2EzMGQzMjQxZjVkMDpzZXNzaW9uX2lkPTJfTVg0ME5Ua3dOamsyTW41LU1UUTVPVEE1T1RRNE9UWTNOMzVXTTJ3d1VERXZRVFZHY0ZVclkxWXdkMWh1Tm0xVGVuQi1VSDQmY3JlYXRlX3RpbWU9MTQ5OTA5OTUxMSZub25jZT0wLjM5NDM2Nzc5MTY2NDQ0OTI0JnJvbGU9cHVibGlzaGVyJmV4cGlyZV90aW1lPTE0OTkxMDMxMDg=

The rest of the code is in

Thanks for the collaboration

```
package com.proyecto.opentoolbox;


import android.webkit.URLUtil;

public class OpenTokConfig {
    // *** Fill the following variables using your own Project info from the OpenTok dashboard  ***
    // ***                      https://dashboard.tokbox.com/projects                           ***


    public static final String API_KEY = "45906962";
    public static final String SESSION_ID = "1_MX40NTkwNjk2Mn5-MTQ5OTEwNTY3ODM2NX5oaUNxOXFDMU1BTTlqL0VmRDFEZXFCcHR-fg";
    public static final String TOKEN = "T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD00NTkwNjk2MiZzaWc9ZjgzYTVhN2IzMmY4OWEzMTgxNGJlYzI3N2JlYWRmODc0MGE3NzFhNDpzZXNzaW9uX2lkPTFfTVg0ME5Ua3dOamsyTW41LU1UUTVPVEV3TlRZM09ETTJOWDVvYVVOeE9YRkRNVTFCVFRscUwwVm1SREZFWlhGQ2NIUi1mZyZjcmVhdGVfdGltZT0xNDk5MTA1NzA4Jm5vbmNlPTAuOTEzNDgxMTA0OTk1NjIzMyZyb2xlPXB1Ymxpc2hlciZleHBpcmVfdGltZT0xNTAxNjk3NzA2";
    public static String API_KEYOtra;
    public static String Api_Key_Radio;
    public static final String Session_Id_Otra = "2_MX40NTkwNjk1Mn5-MTQ5OTEwNTMwODExNn4yUjNtZEVUZ0FrU1RLSXRMZW5OaEIyQ0t-fg";
    public static final String Token_Otra="T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD00NTkwNjk1MiZzaWc9NDYzMjJiMzUyYjkwZmFjOGQxZjMxMWZmYzk1MjE3YzJlNGQ5NmFhNTpzZXNzaW9uX2lkPTJfTVg0ME5Ua3dOamsxTW41LU1UUTVPVEV3TlRNd09ERXhObjR5VWpOdFpFVlVaMEZyVTFSTFNYUk1aVzVPYUVJeVEwdC1mZyZjcmVhdGVfdGltZT0xNDk5MTA1NDA3Jm5vbmNlPTAuNjgwODk4NDc0NTMzMzQ2JnJvbGU9cHVibGlzaGVyJmV4cGlyZV90aW1lPTE1MDE2OTczOTc=";
    public static final String Session_Id_OtraRacio = "2_MX40NTg5NjA2Mn5-MTQ5ODk2NDIxNDkwNX40WWhrcGFEdzJDYjZVRlpUQSsvd2VtdFF-UH4";
    public static final String Token_OtraRadio = "T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD00NTg5NjA2MiZzaWc9ZjhkNDlhMWYwM2ZlNjk5YzhjNzE3ZDRkYTgwYWU1NmQ5YTk4OWEyYzpzZXNzaW9uX2lkPTJfTVg0ME5UZzVOakEyTW41LU1UUTVPRGsyTkRJeE5Ea3dOWDQwV1docmNHRkVkekpEWWpaVlJscFVRU3N2ZDJWdGRGRi1VSDQmY3JlYXRlX3RpbWU9MTQ5ODk2NDI0MCZub25jZT0wLjAxODYyODQwNzM4NDUyMzUzOCZyb2xlPXB1Ymxpc2hlciZleHBpcmVfdGltZT0xNDk4OTY3ODM4JmNvbm5lY3Rpb25fZGF0YT1wcnVlYmElMjByYWRpbw==";

    public OpenTokConfig(){}
    public String getApi_Key() {
        return Api_Key;
    }

    public void setApi_Key(String api_Key) {
        Api_Key = api_Key;
        API_KEYOtra = api_Key;
    }

    public String getSession_Id() {
        return Session_Id;
    }

    public void setSession_Id(String session_Id) {

        Session_Id = session_Id;
        //Session_Id_Otra=session_Id;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return Token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {

        Token = token;
        //Token_Otra=token;
    }


    /*                           ***** OPTIONAL *****
     If you have set up a server to provide session information replace the null value
     in CHAT_SERVER_URL with it.

     For example: "https://yoursubdomain.com"
    */
    public static final String CHAT_SERVER_URL = null;
    public static final String SESSION_INFO_ENDPOINT = CHAT_SERVER_URL + "/session";


    // *** The code below is to validate this configuration file. You do not need to modify it  ***

    public static String webServerConfigErrorMessage;
    public static String hardCodedConfigErrorMessage;

    public static boolean areHardCodedConfigsValid() {
        if (OpenTokConfig.API_KEY != null && !OpenTokConfig.API_KEY.isEmpty()
                && OpenTokConfig.SESSION_ID != null && !OpenTokConfig.SESSION_ID.isEmpty()
                && OpenTokConfig.TOKEN != null && !OpenTokConfig.TOKEN.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            hardCodedConfigErrorMessage = "API KEY, SESSION ID and TOKEN in OpenTokConfig.java cannot be null or empty.";
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isWebServerConfigUrlValid(){
        if (OpenTokConfig.CHAT_SERVER_URL == null || OpenTokConfig.CHAT_SERVER_URL.isEmpty()) {
            webServerConfigErrorMessage = "CHAT_SERVER_URL in OpenTokConfig.java must not be null or empty";
            return false;
        } else if ( !( URLUtil.isHttpsUrl(OpenTokConfig.CHAT_SERVER_URL) || URLUtil.isHttpUrl(OpenTokConfig.CHAT_SERVER_URL)) ) {
            webServerConfigErrorMessage = "CHAT_SERVER_URL in OpenTokConfig.java must be specified as either http or https";
            return false;
        } else if ( !URLUtil.isValidUrl(OpenTokConfig.CHAT_SERVER_URL) ) {
            webServerConfigErrorMessage = "CHAT_SERVER_URL in OpenTokConfig.java is not a valid URL";
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public String getApi_Key_Radio() {
        return Api_Key_Radio;
    }

    public void setApi_Key_Radio(String api_Key_Radio) {
        Api_Key_Radio = api_Key_Radio;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Opentok sessions have a lifespan. Make sure you are not using a token that is still active. If you are creating the tokens using opentok's portal you can set the validity period on the page or if you are using the API, you can specify the validity period as well.